# Is there a name for the new "shake phone" interface convention?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, ui, mobile

Some mobile applications leverage the fact that smart phones have motion sensitivity to provide a "shake" feature.

For example, I believe [Urban Spoon](http://www.urbanspoon.com/) has an app with which you can view a recommendation for a nearby restaurant; if you don't like the recommendation then you can shake your phone and it will immediately come up with another one.

Is there a **word** for this new interface pattern/idiom/convention (or whatever you want to call it)?

Comment: I think a better question is what defines a shake precisely?  How aggressive does one need to move the phone to consider it a shake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everywhere I see it, it is referred to as **"shake"** with various specific words tacked on like *control, touch, phone, interface*, etc.

Stack Overflow just tags it [shake](/questions/tagged/shake).

Some SO questions:

[How Do I Detect When Someone Shakes an Iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone)

[How to use Shake API in iPhone SDK 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170917/how-to-use-shake-api-in-iphone-sdk-3-0)

Comment: Seeing it referred to as "Shake" within the iPhone API itself was all I needed!

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone SDK framework has an event labeled in the documentation and headers as:

```
UIEventSubtypeMotionShake
```

So "shake" sounds like the official name.